# Cannot receive start command

Tags: windows-7, apache-2.2, debugging, zend-optimizer

I have a WAMP install (Apache 2.2.3, PHP 5.2.8) with a working Zend Optimizer.
As soon as I add the php.ini lines for Zend Debugger:

```
[Zend Debugger]
zend_extension_manager.debug_server_ts="C:\zenddebugger"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1/32, 192.168.0.0/16, 192.168.1.0/255
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

and restart apache, I get a blank page and the following entry in the apache error log.

```
[Zend Debugger] Cannot receive start command
[Zend Debugger] Cannot send message
```

Now the incredible thing is that I had it working this morning and now, after reinstalling WAMP there is no way I can get it work again. php.ini is exactly the same as it was before.

I would be extremely glad to get help, I'm trying to get a working server environment going for over a month, can you believe that? I tried XAMPP, Zend Server and now WAMP and I'm going crazy slowly but surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I just found is to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Maybe it's just something with the hosts (hosts.ini) file. But that has been ok so far.

It seems that the Debugger doesn't get the new way Windows 7 is resolving localhost, when I add an entry to the hosts file, I can partly debug. Still, my errand has not come to and end since everything is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my machine to, also running on Windows 7.  Running Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.12